# How to turn a heterogeneous suspension into a homogeneous mixture?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I have a solution into which I put in solid particulates that settle down. How do I turn this into a homogeneous mixture, where the particles are uniformly scattered throughout the solution?

Comment: No problem.  Go into a zero g environment and agitate vigorously.